# Android - Passing Value from ListView to a new Activity?

Tags: android, listview, subview

I have a ListView that shows a list of names. When you select a name, I want to pass the selected person' ID to the next view (Profile) and retreieve their data based on their ID.

I am able to load the Profile View, but do not know how to pass the ID from the ListView to the Profile. Here is how I am loading the Profile:

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {   
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {      
             Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), SubView.class); // when a row is tapped, load SubView.class
             startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); // display SubView.class                  
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hmm I found the put/getExtra. I guess the question now is how to I assign an ID to each row in the ListView...

Comment: How did you pass list of object into array? Please help me with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An intent includes a bundle of extras:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), SubView.class); 
myIntent.putExtra("id", id);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); // display SubView.class
```

In the oncreate method of your profile activity you can access the extras:

```
int id = getIntent().getIntExtra("id");
```

Comment: definitely need to use getIntExtra or getStringExtra.

Answer (score 1):

**First Activity**

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.putExtra("key", "value");
startActivity(myIntent);
```

**New Activity**

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent(); // this is just for example purpose
myIntent.getExtra("key");
```